# How to prevent both divs from toggling content at the same time when either button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a working code but the probelm I'm facing is that when you click the first button and second, both will show the content. I don't want the buttons to be active at the same time. I want them to be independent of the other meaning when one button is showing the other should auto hide it's content. The latter clicked button should take precedence toggling the previous one to hide.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("p." + this.className).toggle("slow");
});
```

```css
p {
  background: #dad;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js">
</script>
<button class="toggle1">Toggle 1</button>
<button class="toggle2">Toggle 2</button>
<p class="toggle1">Hiya</p>
<p class="toggle2">Such interesting text, eh?</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("p[class*=toggle]:not(p." + this.className + ")").hide();
$("button").click(function() {
  $("p[class*=toggle]:not(p." + this.className + ")").hide();
  $("p." + this.className).toggle("slow");
});
```

```css
p {
  background: #dad;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js">
</script>
<button class="toggle1">Toggle 1</button>
<button class="toggle2">Toggle 2</button>
<p class="toggle1">Hiya</p>
<p class="toggle2">Such interesting text, eh?</p>
```

Note:- First you need to hide all the `divs` & then by clicking on button you need to show particular div by using `this` function.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using hide and show functionality you just need to modify your code.

```js
var isButtonClicked=[]
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").hide();
   $("button").click(function(){
      var currentClass=$(this).attr("class");
      if($.inArray(currentClass,isButtonClicked)==-1)
      {
        $("p").hide("slow");
        $("p."+currentClass).show("slow");
        isButtonClicked.push(currentClass);
      }
      else{
         alert("second time you clicked")
         $(this).hide()
      }
   })

})
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>toggle demo</title>
  <style>
    p {
      background: #dad;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <button class="toggle1">Toggle 1</button>
  <button class="toggle2">Toggle 2</button>
  <p class="toggle1">Hiya</p>
  <p class="toggle2">Such interesting text, eh?</p>

</body>
</html>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js">

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way I can add a single hide all others kinda thing so that I only show the current clicked button content.

Comment: @maryongubo answer modified

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still want to hide the content on second click of the same button. This has disappeared on the otherwise working code you added.

Comment: you want to hide a button if its clicked again?

Answer (score 0):

Just hide your `p` before showing them.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("p").hide();
  $("p."+this.className).toggle("slow");
});
```

```css
p{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>toggle demo</title>
  <style>
    p {
      background: #dad;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  
  <button class="toggle1">Toggle 1</button>
  <button class="toggle2">Toggle 2</button>
  <p class="toggle1">Hiya</p>
  <p class="toggle2">Such interesting text, eh?</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed but how do I still maintain hiding the content on second click of the same button?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("p[class*=toggle]:not(p."+this.className+")").hide();
  $("p."+this.className).toggle("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
p[class*=toggle] {display:none}
p {
  background: #dad;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}
</style>

<button class="toggle1">Toggle 1</button>
<button class="toggle2">Toggle 2</button>
<button class="toggle3">Toggle 3</button>
<p class="toggle1">Hiya</p>
<p class="toggle2">Such interesting text, eh?</p>
<p class="toggle3">Another one</p>
```